# Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? (truffle, web3js)

Tags: solidity, truffle, out-of-gas

why this error can occur?

```
Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
```

I am using Truffle, WEB3.JS, Metamask (connected to the localhost);
(web3 : ^1.6.0)
(solidity in truffle-config.js: 0.8.0)

- I checked the ABI - it's okay.
- I tried to use "truffle migrate --reset all"
- I tried different solutions from internet - nothing helps (even identical cases).

My contract:

```
contract OfferFactory {

    function getHealthCheck() public view returns(string memory) {
        return "Works fine!";
    }
}
```

Front-End code:

```
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(OFFER_FACTORY_ABI, '0x9708aE5C8a34e45448330BC5d881B59C389f358B');

console.log(contract);

const res = await contract.methods.getHealthCheck().call(function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("An error occured", err) // error is here.
    return
  }
  console.log("Result: ", res)
})
```

Can you please help me? What should I additionally check? Maybe you need me provide some extra information?

Comment: Hi Karelin! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Are you testing against ganache or a testnetwork? The problem could be the contract's address or abi are wrong.

Comment: Try with another network. For me I solve this issue by using `ganache` network.

Comment: Same problem here and it has nothing to do with abi or solidity code as it gets to work sometimes and not others.

Comment: Same problem, probably the last part of the sentence: "querying a node which is not fully synced." . I wonder if there are a way to recreate a connection with the Provider after a wait when we detect such problem.